# Hilbert representation with compactness and *-property

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a continuous representation $\pi$ of a Lie group $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$, not unitary.
Suppose that

- it is a $\star$-representation for the Lie algebra, i.e., $\pi(X)^\star=\pi(-X)$ on the smooth vectors and
- every $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$ acts by a compact operator.

What can I say about the representation? Does it have a direct sum decomposition into irreducibles? If not, a filtration with irreducible quotients?